# find all combinations of words from a list of lists,by choosing 1 word from each list using Java without using recursion

Tags: java

Given : 
    `[["quick","lazy"],["brown","grey"],["fox","dog"]]`

find all combinations by choosing only 1 word from each list using Java.

- The solution should work for any such List of lists
- best time complexity possible
- without using recursion

My solution:

```
public static <T> Set<List<T>> getCombinations(List<List<T>> lists) {
    Set<List<T>> combinations = new HashSet<List<T>>();
    Set<List<T>> newCombinations;

    int index = 0;

    // extract each of the integers in the first list
    // and add each to ints as a new list
    for(T i: lists.get(0)) {
        List<T> newList = new ArrayList<T>();
        newList.add(i);
        combinations.add(newList);
    }
    index++;
    while(index < lists.size()) {
        List<T> nextList = lists.get(index);
        newCombinations = new HashSet<List<T>>();
        for(List<T> first: combinations) {
            for(T second: nextList) {
                List<T> newList = new ArrayList<T>();
                newList.addAll(first);
                newList.add(second);
                newCombinations.add(newList);
            }
        }
        combinations = newCombinations;

        index++;
    }

    return combinations;
}
```

Comment: Can you list the expected output. That would be helpful.

Comment: We don't want to see questions straight from your homework, we've already done our dues. What part are you struggling with? Have you tried anything?

Comment: @J.Knight I want to improve time complexity without using recursion.Is that possible?

Comment: I don't believe this will be possible without using recursion but this should be able to be simplified, just run a nested for loop for the inner and outer lists and then add the resulting combination to the HashSet each time and it will not allow any duplicates.

Comment: May I ask why your solution is referring to integers when you're actually working with strings?

Comment: @J.Knight Sure you can do it without recursion.

Comment: I'dd be very interested to see the solution to this, I was playing around with it a bit earlier but wasn't able to get a solution up and running. Might have to spend some more time on it later :P

Comment: @J.Knight Well then, [have a look](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44664519/5221149).

Comment: @DanCarter I was initially using Integers

Comment: This is a very specific homework question; Stackoverflow is not a tutor

Answer (score 1):

Here are two different solutions to this. For both, the input has been extended to show that it can handle a varying number of values in each sublist.

The first solution calculates the total number of combinations, then iterates through each "numbered" combination, calculating which value to use from each sublist. This solution should only be used if sublists are array-based, as it uses `get(int index)`, otherwise performance will be degraded.

The second solution is made as open as possible, i.e. outer "list" can be any `Collection`, and "sublists" can be any kind of `Iterable`. It generates a bit more garbage, since it has to keep re-creating iterators, but that shouldn't be a problem (GC is good these days).

For variation, the two solutions generate the combinations in a different order, but they can both be changed to do it the other way.

**Solution 1**

```
public static <T> List<List<T>> getCombinations(List<List<T>> valueSetList) {
    int comboCount = 1;
    for (List<T> valueSet : valueSetList)
        comboCount = Math.multiplyExact(comboCount, valueSet.size()); // Fail if overflow
    List<List<T>> combinations = new ArrayList<>(comboCount);
    for (int comboNumber = 0; comboNumber < comboCount; comboNumber++) {
        List<T> combination = new ArrayList<>(valueSetList.size());
        int remain = comboNumber;
        for (List<T> valueSet : valueSetList) {
            combination.add(valueSet.get(remain % valueSet.size()));
            remain /= valueSet.size();
        }
        combinations.add(combination);
    }
    return combinations;
}
```

**Solution 2**

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> List<List<T>> getCombinations(Collection<? extends Iterable<T>> valueSetCollection) {
    Iterable<T>[] valueSets = new Iterable[valueSetCollection.size()];
    Iterator<T>[] valueIters  = new Iterator[valueSetCollection.size()];
    T[] values = (T[]) new Object[valueSetCollection.size()];
    int i = 0;
    for (Iterable<T> valueSet : valueSetCollection) {
        valueSets[i] = valueSet; // Copy to array for fast index lookup
        valueIters[i] = valueSet.iterator();
        values[i] = valueIters[i].next(); // Fail if a wordSet is empty
        i++;
    }
    List<List<T>> combinations = new ArrayList<>();
    NEXT_COMBO: for (;;) {
        combinations.add(Arrays.asList(values.clone()));
        for (i = values.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (valueIters[i].hasNext()) {
                values[i] = valueIters[i].next();
                continue NEXT_COMBO;
            }
            valueIters[i] = valueSets[i].iterator();
            values[i] = valueIters[i].next();
        }
        return combinations;
    }
}
```

**Test**

```
getCombinations(Arrays.asList(
        Arrays.asList("quick","lazy"),
        Arrays.asList("brown","grey","black","red"),
        Arrays.asList("fox","dog","wolf")
)).forEach(System.out::println);
```

**Output 1**

```
[quick, brown, fox]
[lazy, brown, fox]
[quick, grey, fox]
[lazy, grey, fox]
[quick, black, fox]
[lazy, black, fox]
[quick, red, fox]
[lazy, red, fox]
[quick, brown, dog]
[lazy, brown, dog]
[quick, grey, dog]
[lazy, grey, dog]
[quick, black, dog]
[lazy, black, dog]
[quick, red, dog]
[lazy, red, dog]
[quick, brown, wolf]
[lazy, brown, wolf]
[quick, grey, wolf]
[lazy, grey, wolf]
[quick, black, wolf]
[lazy, black, wolf]
[quick, red, wolf]
[lazy, red, wolf]
```

**Output 2**

```
[quick, brown, fox]
[quick, brown, dog]
[quick, brown, wolf]
[quick, grey, fox]
[quick, grey, dog]
[quick, grey, wolf]
[quick, black, fox]
[quick, black, dog]
[quick, black, wolf]
[quick, red, fox]
[quick, red, dog]
[quick, red, wolf]
[lazy, brown, fox]
[lazy, brown, dog]
[lazy, brown, wolf]
[lazy, grey, fox]
[lazy, grey, dog]
[lazy, grey, wolf]
[lazy, black, fox]
[lazy, black, dog]
[lazy, black, wolf]
[lazy, red, fox]
[lazy, red, dog]
[lazy, red, wolf]
```

Comment: Good job mate :)

Comment: @Andreas the time complexity of solution 1 is O(n^2). Is it an improvement over mine?

Comment: @sach20 I don't see how it's _O(n^2)_, but then again I don't know what you define `n` to be. Performance of solution 1 is _O(nm)_, where `n` is number of combinations, and `m` is number of values per combination. It's impossible to be less than that, because you have to add that many values to result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public static <T> Set<List<T>> getCombinations(List<List<T>> lists) {
    int max = 1;
    for (List<T> list : lists)
        max *= list.size();
    Set<List<T>> result = new HashSet<>(max);
    for (int i = 0; i < max; ++i) {
        List<T> newSublist = new ArrayList<>();
        int n = i;
        for (List<T> list : lists) {
            int size = list.size();
            newSublist.add(list.get(n % size));
            n /= size;
        }
        result.add(newSublist);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: the time complexity of your solution is O(n^2).Is that an improvement over mine?